# Standard Word templates, fonts, etcetera. for non/semi-technical Springer journals?

Tags: journals, formatting

Is there a standard typeface and/or word template that people use when submitting to non/semi-technical Springer journals? Previously I have always used Latex, which typically meant a conference or similar template was used. I have obviously searched but could not find anything, so I am wondering what the unofficial, if one exists, standard is?

I ask because I think it does give a better impression if the standard formatting that reviewers are used to is used.

Comment: Did you check the journal in question, i.e. checked the springer homepage or asked if there is a template you should use when submitting to this journal?

Comment: I have, there are Word templates for a technical field (Computer Science). Springer advises against using Word for this field, it's not the field for this paper in any case. I'm trying to find something for a non-technical field that formats everything just as Latex classes do.

Comment: @ThomasKing Just use a default LaTeX class, e.g., article.

Comment: Thanks, I'm asking for Word templates though.

Answer (score 2):

Springer offers the [SVJour3 Latex class](http://www.e-publications.org/springer/support/spr-chicago.html) (with a [manual](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1007%2Fs40571-014-0022-7/MediaObjects/40571_2014_22_MOESM5_ESM.pdf)) for preparing manuscripts for Springer journals.

I use Latex for its referencing and figure-handling capabilities, but I submit most of my work to social-science journals, not all of which have Latex templates. In general, managing editors at these journals are expecting submissions to be in Word. However, the typesetting at large publishers such as Springer is typically done by central teams that can handle a wide range of formats. As such, there is no technical problem in submitting Latex files but you have to overcome the editor's unfamiliarity with this format.

To do that, the following has always worked for me.

1. Submit the article as a PDF, with the Latex file, Bib file and any figures in a Zip archive as supplementary material. Crucially, include an extremely polite cover note to the editor:

   - explaining that the manuscript has been prepared in Latex so there is no Word version,
   - reassuring them that the publisher's production department will be familiar with handling Latex files,
   - suggesting that they contact their production editor if they aren't sure if they can accept this format.
2. Expect the managing editor to reject the article out-of-hand because your manuscript is a PDF and they haven't read your cover note.
3. Reply to the rejection by emailing the managing editor, again (very politely) asking them to contact their production department to check if they can accept Latex. You may also want to explain (briefly) why you've written the manuscript in Latex (maybe because Word can't handle special characters or equations very well).

Step 3 generally produces a 'well you learn something every day' reply from the managing editor. If they still won't accept it, you may have to copy your manuscript over to Word ([overview of options for doing that](https://www.tug.org/utilities/texconv/textopc.html)). Think carefully, though, since converting to Word may require lots of manual formatting/checking that you will then have to repeat if you make any changes during the peer-review process.

One reason you might not want to do submit in Latex is that the above procedure slightly increases the workload of journal editors, who are typically working for free. On the other hand, you may feel that it's worth it because you're helping future authors who may want to submit manuscripts prepared in Latex for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You could try other editors like authorea or typeset. These are based on latex (and include lots of journal templates) but you can export the draft as a .docx file.

Answer (score 0):

The Word or Latex class are located here: https://www.springer.com/de/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/manuscript-preparation/5636

Note. I'm having severe issues with the Word template, specifically the macro doesn't seem to work well cross-Word, e.g. when using different machines with different Word versions.
I think Spring should update this and make the release of this "tool" much more clear.